# Set coverage by elements

Tags: optimization, algorithms

Given a set of elements and each of those elements have features (out of a finite set). What algorithm can I use to find the smallest set of features so that every element would have at least one of those features?

I try to look at using the Set Cover algorithm, but cannot find how to use it here.

In addition, if I add another constraint of picking a maximum of $k$ features, how can I find the set that would provide the most coverage?

---

For example. If I have all the flag of countries in the world, each of them have some colors (assuming there is no flag with gradients here). How can I find the smallest set of colors so that every flag has at least one of those color.

If I have

```
F = { USA, France, Germany, Italy, Sweden, Romania, Gabon }

USA -> { red, white, blue }
France -> { blue, white, red }
Germany -> { black, red, yellow }
Italy -> { red, white, green }
Sweden -> { blue, yellow }
Romania -> { blue, yellow, red }
Gabon -> { green, yellow, blue }

C = { red, blue, white, black, yellow, green, orange }
```

I would like the algorithm to return:

```
{yellow, red}
```

Comment: Incidentally, the colours of the olympic rings are supposed to solve the concrete problem about flag colours (contrary to the popular belief that they somehow represent continents)

Comment: The citation on this wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olympic_symbols under "Different types of flags" suggests that there are $5$ rings because there are $5$ continents. But the colors were chosen to match flags of nations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your first question: What you are given is exactly the set cover problem: You have $n$ elements and $m$ sets of those elements (For each attribute you can group all elements with that attribute in one set). Note that this is known to be NP-complete. On Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem you can find out how to solve it using ILP.

Update:

Note that your second problem is also NP-complete because it is more general than your first problem. In other words: If you can solve your second problem in general then this gives you a method to solve your first problem.